# Azure functions service bus trigger settings maxAutoLockRenewalDuration or maxAutoRenewDuration doesn't seem to take effect

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure function runtime 4 and .Net 7 Isolated. I tried both **maxAutoLockRenewalDuration** and **maxAutoRenewDuration** in host.json for an Azure functions service bus trigger function that runs for an hour. The setting from host.json does not take effect and it always locks timeout at the message lock duration of 5 minutes set at Azure service bus topic subscription. Below is the code used to load the host.json. What could be the potential issue?

```
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
            {

                // obtain host.json configs
                var config = configBuilder.Build();
                
                IConfigurationBuilder builder = configBuilder
                          .AddConfiguration(config)
                          .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                          .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables();

                var hostingEnvAppSettings = string.Empty;

                if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    hostingEnvAppSettings = "appSettings.Development.json";
                else if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsStaging())
                    hostingEnvAppSettings = "appSettings.staging.json";
                else if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                    hostingEnvAppSettings = "appSettings.Production.json";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostingEnvAppSettings))
                    builder.AddJsonFile(hostingEnvAppSettings, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                var builtConfig = builder.Build();

                if (!hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    int configRefreshSeconds = int.TryParse(builtConfig["ConfigRefreshSeconds"], out configRefreshSeconds) ? configRefreshSeconds : 600;

                    var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                        new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                        new DefaultAzureCredential());

                    // added code to refresh config by polling
                    configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        secretClient,
                        new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
                        {
                            Manager = new KeyVaultSecretManager(),
                            ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configRefreshSeconds)
                        });
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Jobs startup configuration {builtConfig["ConfigRefreshSeconds"]} {builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]} {builtConfig.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")}");
            })
```

host.json snippet:

Attempt 1:

```
    "serviceBus": {
      // Maximum time to which locked message automatically renewed by the client
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "02:00:00"
    }
  }
```

Attempt 2:

```
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "02:00:00" // Maximum time to which locked message automatically renewed by the client
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I use Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.15.0. Run method params below. It looks like maxAutoLockRenewalDuration works but I see that lock is lost at random times and another instance pickup from the queue.

       [Function("MyFunction")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("mynotification", "mynotification-sub", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
            string body)
        {}

Comment: The error I see in appinsights log is 409 "LeaseIdMismatchWithLeaseOperation". Btw, I'm not using any blocking operations, everything is async. Just need to know how to control auto refresh frequency/duration of lock renewal.

Comment: What does your Function signature look like?   Automatic lock renewal does not apply to batch-based functions.

Comment: [Function("BackendJobMessagingTriggerFunction")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("backend-job", "backend-job-sub", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string body, 
            FunctionContext context
            )
        {
....
        }

Comment: This issue happens quite frequently if Message lock duration is set to 5 minutes for the topic subscription in Azure portal and when using Elastic Premium subscription for Azure Function App. I have not noted this issue with dedicated premium plan.  Also setting Message lock duration to 3 minutes reduce the occurrence of the issue on Elastic Premium. I can't explain why.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this one, and it seems that it requires deeper investigation than is appropriate for StackOverflow.  I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure SDK repository so that we can collect more information and work through a repro: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues